# Fetch jcr:created from cq:page AEM 6.3.0

Tags: jcr, aem-6

We need to fetch the jcr:created date for cq:Page (TestTouchRTE).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hf6ZP.png)

I am using

```
<c:set var="createdDate" value="${pageProperties['jcr:created']}"/>
```

This is giving jcr:content created date i.e. of cq:PageContent

, instead I want the jcr:created date of cq:Page.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch this from the page properties in sightly like:

${ 'yyyy-MM-dd' @ format=pageProperties.jcr:created}